# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "InvoiceDate"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am running 3 PostgreSQL queries which is running fine but when I am doing UNION ALL to all the 3 queries then I am getting ERROR.

Below are my queries.

```
 SELECT 'ContactName' as "ContactName",'InvoiceNumber' as "InvoiceNumber",'InvoiceDate' as "InvoiceDate",'DueDate' as "DueDate",'Description' as "Description",'Quantity' as "Quantity",'UnitAmount' as "UnitAmount",'AccountCode' as "AccountCode",'TaxType' as "TaxType",'TaxAmount' as "TaxAmount";
```

**Result: Success**

```
 SELECT c.organization_name as "CUSTOMER",CONCAT(i.id) as "INVOICE",DATE(i.create_datetime) as "INVOICE_DATE",DATE(i.due_date) as "DUE_DATE",CONCAT('Invoice ID1-',i.id,' - REGULAR VAT LINES') as "DESCRIPTION",'1' AS "QTY",round((COALESCE(NULLIF((SELECT sum(il.amount) AS vat FROM invoice_line il WHERE il.invoice_id = i.id AND il.description LIKE '%VAT%' AND il.description != 'VAT @20%' AND il.item_id = 200 AND il.deleted = 0),null),'0')*5),2) as SUB_TOTAL_DUE_AT_STANDARD_VAT20,'200' AS "ACCOUNT_CODE",'20% (VAT on Income)' AS "TAX_TYPE",round((COALESCE(NULLIF((SELECT sum(il.amount) AS vat FROM invoice_line il WHERE il.invoice_id = i.id AND il.description LIKE '%VAT%' AND il.description != 'VAT @20%' AND il.item_id = 200 AND il.deleted = 0),null),'0')*5),2) as VAT_AT_STANDARD_VAT20 FROM invoice i,base_user bu,contact c WHERE bu.id = i.user_id AND c.user_id = i.user_id AND i.total != 0 AND i.is_review = 0 AND i.deleted = 0 AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'Skyrack%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'Simetric%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'PBX Test%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'ZZZTEST%';
```

**Result: Success**

```
 SELECT c.organization_name as "CUSTOMER",CONCAT(i.id) as "INVOICE",DATE(i.create_datetime) as "INVOICE_DATE",DATE(i.due_date) as "DUE_DATE",CONCAT('Invoice ID1-',i.id,' - REVCHG VAT LINES') as "DESCRIPTION",'1' AS "QTY",round(((i.total - COALESCE(NULLIF((SELECT sum(il.amount) AS vat FROM invoice_line il WHERE il.invoice_id = i.id AND il.description LIKE '%VAT%' AND il.description != 'VAT @20%' AND il.item_id = 200 AND il.deleted = 0),null),'0'))-(COALESCE(NULLIF((SELECT sum(il.amount) AS vat FROM invoice_line il WHERE il.invoice_id = i.id AND il.description LIKE '%VAT%' AND il.description != 'VAT @20%' AND il.item_id = 200 AND il.deleted = 0),null),'0')* 5)),2) AS "SUB_TOTAL_DUE_AT_VAT0",'210' AS "ACCOUNT_CODE",'Domestic Reverse Charge' AS "TAX_TYPE",'0' AS "VAT_AT_STANDARD_VAT0" FROM invoice i,base_user bu,contact c WHERE bu.id = i.user_id AND c.user_id = i.user_id AND i.total != 0 AND i.is_review = 0 AND i.deleted = 0 AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'Skyrack%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'Simetric%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'PBX Test%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'ZZZTEST%';
```

**Result: Success**

Now when I am doing UNION ALL For all 3 queries as

```
 SELECT 'ContactName' as "ContactName",'InvoiceNumber' as "InvoiceNumber",'InvoiceDate' as "InvoiceDate",'DueDate' as "DueDate",'Description' as "Description",'Quantity' as "Quantity",'UnitAmount' as "UnitAmount",'AccountCode' as "AccountCode",'TaxType' as "TaxType",'TaxAmount' as "TaxAmount" UNION ALL SELECT c.organization_name as "CUSTOMER",CONCAT(i.id) as "INVOICE",DATE(i.create_datetime) as "INVOICE_DATE",DATE(i.due_date) as "DUE_DATE",CONCAT('Invoice ID1-',i.id,' - REGULAR VAT LINES') as "DESCRIPTION",'1' AS "QTY",round((COALESCE(NULLIF((SELECT sum(il.amount) AS vat FROM invoice_line il WHERE il.invoice_id = i.id AND il.description LIKE '%VAT%' AND il.description != 'VAT @20%' AND il.item_id = 200 AND il.deleted = 0),null),'0')*5),2) as SUB_TOTAL_DUE_AT_STANDARD_VAT20,'200' AS "ACCOUNT_CODE",'20% (VAT on Income)' AS "TAX_TYPE",round((COALESCE(NULLIF((SELECT sum(il.amount) AS vat FROM invoice_line il WHERE il.invoice_id = i.id AND il.description LIKE '%VAT%' AND il.description != 'VAT @20%' AND il.item_id = 200 AND il.deleted = 0),null),'0')*5),2) as VAT_AT_STANDARD_VAT20 FROM invoice i,base_user bu,contact c WHERE bu.id = i.user_id AND c.user_id = i.user_id AND i.total != 0 AND i.is_review = 0 AND i.deleted = 0 AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'Skyrack%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'Simetric%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'PBX Test%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'ZZZTEST%' UNION ALL SELECT c.organization_name as "CUSTOMER",CONCAT(i.id) as "INVOICE",DATE(i.create_datetime) as "INVOICE_DATE",DATE(i.due_date) as "DUE_DATE",CONCAT('Invoice ID1-',i.id,' - REVCHG VAT LINES') as "DESCRIPTION",'1' AS "QTY",round(((i.total - COALESCE(NULLIF((SELECT sum(il.amount) AS vat FROM invoice_line il WHERE il.invoice_id = i.id AND il.description LIKE '%VAT%' AND il.description != 'VAT @20%' AND il.item_id = 200 AND il.deleted = 0),null),'0'))-(COALESCE(NULLIF((SELECT sum(il.amount) AS vat FROM invoice_line il WHERE il.invoice_id = i.id AND il.description LIKE '%VAT%' AND il.description != 'VAT @20%' AND il.item_id = 200 AND il.deleted = 0),null),'0')* 5)),2) AS "SUB_TOTAL_DUE_AT_VAT0",'210' AS "ACCOUNT_CODE",'Domestic Reverse Charge' AS "TAX_TYPE",'0' AS "VAT_AT_STANDARD_VAT0" FROM invoice i,base_user bu,contact c WHERE bu.id = i.user_id AND c.user_id = i.user_id AND i.total != 0 AND i.is_review = 0 AND i.deleted = 0 AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'Skyrack%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'Simetric%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'PBX Test%' AND c.organization_name NOT LIKE 'ZZZTEST%';
```

**Result: Failed**

> Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "InvoiceDate"

I am not getting what is making this error & how to fix it ?[image]

Comment: In your first SELECT you have InvoiceDate as a text.  In the other two it is a date.  You cannot mix types in a UNION.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock, thanks Jonathan , I got your point. Does it restricted to only in PostgreSQL or MySQl as well ? I am trying to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL & for MySQL, UNION ALL It's working fine. Can you give your inputs on this ?

Comment: You could cast everything to text to match the first query, but overall this seems pretty strange.  Why use the first row as headers instead of the column identifiers?